# More readable way to set a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a shorter, more readable way to set a variable depending on another variable? ("mapping" the values):

```
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] ; then res="OK" ; else res="ERROR" ; fi
```

### EDIT

In python you can do:

```
res = "OK" if xxx = 0 else "ERR"
```

Which is very readable

Comment: What do you call a _more readable way_ ?, is this more readable `[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && res="OK" || res="ERROR" `

Comment: @Inian not really!

Comment: What else then? What you have is reasonably good. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Inian edited my question

Comment: not all constructs are available in the same way in all languages, Good luck! searching for it in `bash`

Comment: IMO this would be shortest: `res='OK'; (($?)) && res='ERROR'`

Comment: Your Python syntax is wrong

Comment: @anubhava, `res=OK;` effect $? is set to 0, `(($?))` is an arithmetic evaluation of exit status is the contrary 0 => false

Comment: What I meant: `res='OK'; your-command; (($?)) && res='ERROR'`

Comment: I have to say, if that python syntax was correct, I have no idea how you view that as readable.  The shortest method in bash would be to set it and then only change for the value you need it changed.

Answer (score 1):

Since your testing the exit status of a command, you could just use the command in conditional construct.

```
if command; then ....; else ....; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be noted that in this particular case the following works:

```
the-command && res=OK || res=ERROR
```

it is not recommended to use `&&` and `||` in the same line because it's not equivalent to `if` `else` ; in the case the expression after the `&&` has a fail status the last expression will be executed.
Generally `&&` or `||` are used in shell to check the status and exit fast.

A creative way

```
exit_codes=(OK ERROR)

...

res=${exit_codes[$?==0?0:1]}
```

Ternary operator exists for arithmetic operations

Another way based on default substitutions

```
res=${?#0} res=${res:+ERROR} res=${res:-OK}; echo $res

# res=${?#0}        #removes the leading 0 of $? -> empty if success
# res=${res:+ERROR} #res is set to ERROR if x is not empty, empty otherwise
# res=${res:-OK}  #res is set to OK if empty, ERROR otherwise
```

but this is not readable

Comment: On a lighter note, is this supposed to more readable ;)

Comment: after the EDIT it seemed to me the user wanted a ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

Start out with a trivial array:

```
msgs=(ERROR OK)
```

Now, index the array with `!$?`; an exit status of 0 results in 1, and an exit status of any non-zero value results in 0.

```
$ true; res=${msgs[!$?]}; echo "$res"
OK
$ false; res=${msg[!$?]}; echo "$res"
ERROR
```